# Is there a way to get the intensity of shaking?

Tags: ios, swift

I am doing a POC to see if i can find the intensity of shake.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func motionBegan(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("started shaking!")
    }

    override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        println("ended shaking!")
    }
}
```

I don't see anything which can tell me how intense the shake was. In my case, this shake could be a continuous event for a few seconds.

Comment: You can read accelerometer output.

Comment: Any examples..or links to share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I put in the didAccelerate callback with a few class variables and constants:

```
UIAccelerationValue accelX, accelY, accelZ;
#define  kAccelerometerFrequency 25 //Hz
#define  kFilteringFactor 0.1
#define  kMinShakeInterval 0.1
#define  kShakeAccelerationThreshold 0.2
-(CMMotionManager*) motionManager{
    if (_motionManager==nil) {
        _motionManager=[[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
        _motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval=1.0/25;
        _motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval=1.0/25;
    }
    return _motionManager;
}
-(void) viewDidLoad{
   [...]
   [[self motionManager] startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                                           withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData  *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {
                                               [self didAccelerate:accelerometerData.acceleration];
                                               if(error){
                                                   NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                               }
                                           }];
    [...]
}

- (void)didAccelerate:(CMAcceleration)acceleration{
    UIAccelerationValue lenght, x, y, z;
    accelX=acceleration.x*kFilteringFactor + accelX * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
    accelY=acceleration.y*kFilteringFactor + accelY * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);
    accelZ=acceleration.z*kFilteringFactor + accelZ * (1.0 - kFilteringFactor);

    x=acceleration.x - accelX;
    y=acceleration.y - accelY;
    z=acceleration.z - accelZ;

    lenght=sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z);
    if (lenght>=kShakeAccelerationThreshold && (CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()>lastTime + kMinShakeInterval)){
    //execute shaking actions on main thread
    }
}
```

Comment: what is 'lastTime' in this case.

Comment: I forgot it: it is set in the conditioned block after some specific operations for my app: lastTime=CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent(); and it is a CFTimeInterval lastTime;

Answer (score 1):

You can read the raw stream of accelerometer values using the [`CoreMotion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMDeviceMotion_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMDeviceMotion) framework.

Comment: Any examples or links to share.